# Authorize Android Game - Where is the app-id?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to authorize my android game for google play services to be able to use leaderboards etc.

Now when clicking on authorize app, Nothing would happen. On the information page Google tells me to do following things:

[image]

I shall specify my application id, but where do i get this "app_id" from? And achievement id? leaderdboard id?

How should this ids.xml look like?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

On the bottom of your 'leaderboards' or 'achievements' page is a handy link labeled 'Get resources'. This will open a page looking something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!--
Google Play game services IDs.
Save this file as res/values/games-ids.xml in your project.
-->
<resources>
  <string name="app_id">00000000000</string>
  <string name="achievement_xxx">0000000000</string>
  <string name="achievement_yyy">0000000000</string>
 <string name="leaderboard_xxx">000000000000</string>
</resources>
```

Note that you are directed to put this in a file with an illegal name, 'games-ids.xml'. Eclipse won't let you use a dash in a file name, so either put it in your 'strings.xml' file or use 'ids.xml' for the file name as you planned to, I found both to work.

Comment: Note that you actually have to define some achievements first; otherwise the link won't appear. (It didn't appear for me, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Google Developer Console][1]

[1]: http://play.google.com/apps/publish and select the applications in Game Services section, the app id is besides the title of app.